# New form elements' look in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed that the look of the form elements in Chrome has changed. I couldn't find any explanation with a quick search. Even the official Chrome's blog doesn't mention anything. I must say, the new look feels a bit foreign.

I would like to find out the reason behind the change. My guess would be that it has something to do with rendering speed. Is there the official benchmarks of the old look vs new look.

The speed might not be the reason. Does anyone know the official reason?

Comment: Whew, some company changed their logo – why? My girlfriend changed her hair color – why? Some guy with spray paint changed the style of my house – why?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look into the official reason, but I noticed that checkbox elements are now vector graphics so they can scale/resize (like in the newer Internet Explorer).

The Chrome changelog probably has the answers you seek, but I'm guessing they wanted them with more consistent usability/presentation across platforms instead of using the OS' native look and feel.